# I am getting an error message box when attempting a VLOOKUP, Index Match, or XLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I've never encountered this kind of issue before. Working in Excel 365 x64.

I currently have the following formula in a cell and it is working properly:

`=IFERROR(IF(D9=""|""|(VLOOKUP($D9|SpecialistInfo|6|FALSE))-(SUM((H9*$H$7)|(I9*$I$7)|(J9*$J$7)|(K9*$K$7)|(L9*$L$7)|(N9*$N$7)|(O9*$O$7)|(P9*$P$7)|(Q9*$Q$7)|(R9*$R$7)|(S9*$S$7)|(T9*$T$7)|(U9*$U$7)|(V9*$V$7)|(W9*$W$7)|(X9*$X$7)|(Y9*$Y$7)|(Z9*$Z$7)|(AA9*$AA$7)|(AB9*$AB$7)|(AC9*$AC$7)|(AD9*$AD$7)|(AE9*$AE$7)|(AF9*$AF$7)|(AG9*$AG$7)|(AH9*$AH$7)|(AI9*$AI$7)|(AJ9*$AJ$7)|(AK9*$AK$7)|(AL9*$AL$7)|(AM9*$AM$7)|(AN9*$AN$7)|(AO9*$AO$7)|(AP9*$AP$7)|(AQ9*$AQ$7)|(AR9*$AR$7)|(AS9*$AS$7)|(AT9*$AT$7)|(AU9*$AU$7)|(AV9*$AV$7)|(AW9*$AW$7)|(AX9*$AX$7)|(AY9*$AY$7)|(AZ9*$AZ$7)|(BA9*$BA$7)|(BB9*$BB$7)|(BC9*$BC$7)))-IF(BI9>0|120|0))|"")`

However, when I try to do a simple `VLOOKUP` in a different cell, I get the following error:
[image: Vlookup Error]

The error seems to be pointing to the `Col_Index_Num` portion of the `VLOOKUP` formula... so it's looking at Column 6 and column 6 is populated.

Keep in mind that this is the same VBA that is nested into the `IF` and `IFERROR` formulas above. So we know the Table Array is fine.

NOTE: Even though the formula is working right now, I get the same error when I try to add another column to the nested `SUM` formula (e.g. `|(BC9*$BD$7)`).

Has anyone ever encountered this issue? Please help!

I've tried an `IF` formula in the same cell where I had the simple `VLOOKUP` formula. The `IF` formula works in that cell.

I get the same issue when I perform an Index Match or an `XLOOKUP` instead of the `VLookup`.

I have checked for issues in the Table Array.

I have checked for issues in the Table Naming convention/Named Range.

Comment: Wow, I've never seen `|` used as the formula separator.

Comment: Enter that formula using the function wizard (the fx icon on your screehsot). What does it produce?

Comment: @BigBen, yeah, I prefer pipe separators to be consistent with most of my ITL methods.

Comment: @GSerg It produces results for each line...but does not produce a Formula Result

Comment: Additional Info...converted the Table to a Range and VLookup worked fine.  I'll just Convert another column to a Named Range with an Offset formula and leave this as a Range instead of a table

Comment: Can you give an overview of the data table or excel photo?@Qwest336

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to blank cells in the range you're summing the products over.

This is at least when I convert your blanks to "" values using a function.

Your syntax is also completely incompatible with my Excel (Office 365) version. I would be surprised if this was not generally the case - the first time I've ever seen or heard of syntax like this for Excel.

PS - Whilst outside the scope of this question, it is worth noting that you should make (better) use of far more robust functions available at your fingertips.

For instance, the portion of code relating to non-blanks etc. compresses to:

```
=LET(x1_,H7:BC7,x2_,H9:BC9,y_,IFERROR(IF(D9=",",(VLOOKUP($D9,SpecialistInfo,6,FALSE))-SUM(x1_*x2_)-IF(BI9>0,120,0)),""),SUM(IFERROR(x1_*x2_,"")))
```

[image: Efficient method for intrer]